# How to upload large files >5mb in API Gateway? using serverless and nodejs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I am doing an API that recieves  multiple files, (I read them and then upload them on S3)
but i have problems with large files >5mb, only when it recives some small files works,
I think it is API Gateway, that only accepts a limit size of request
but even if  that's right I don't know how to change those values

I am using nodejs, express, multer (multipart/form-data) and serverless
for that API, I upload the files with the function putObject

Could someone help me please?
Is it really API Gatewy the problem? how solve it?
Or what do you think it is the problem?

---

thanks for the answer the error that I get with files >5mb is this

The response body is `{"message": "Internal server error"}`,

headers are:

```
Connection → keep-alive
Content-Length → 36
Content-Type → application/json
Date → Wed, 20 Jan 2016 21:49:57 GMT
Via → 1.1 bacf4777806846760313f3a392450fc4.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id → CjIEJj6FlzXMZO3ht4mGU94L5LMBGjWQq921ddkMUCs96NPxswGIwA==
X-Cache → Error from cloudfront
x-amzn-RequestId → bf549be8-bfbf-11e5-9a15-c9a39c4aad35
```

I'm gonna check the Uploading Objects Using Pre-Signed URLs i did't know them

Do you have any idea why i can't handle files >5mb?

---

**edit**

I've been looking and I saw that lambda AWS has a limit of 6 mb, I think it's another problem, if I upload the file using pre-signed URLs, will the problem be solved?

Comment: I have run into the same problem. Files ~<5mb are being uploaded but not greater than 5 mb. Did you find any solution for your problem? (Except for putting the file directly into S3 via gateway)

Answer (score 3):

How much files does your API receive in a second?

The `Payload size` limit of an API Gateway is 10MB and **cannot** be increased (its a hardlimit). But if you say that it already doesnt work with files of 5MB this shouldnt be the issue...
Do you receive any kind of errors while uploading >5MB, <10MB files?

A helpful link to discover [API Gateway Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html#api-gateway-limits).

To answer your second question: `how solve it?`

An alternative would be to use [Pre-Signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) to upload (`putObject`) files to S3.